# Ao carregar meu arquivo xlsx no pandas, as linhas viraram índices das colunas. Como definir um novo indice para as colunas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Gostaria de saber como definir novo índice para as colunas.

```
data = pd.read_excel('numero_automoveis_vendidos.xlsx')
data.columns
Index([7, 5, 9, 11, 10, 8, '9.1', 6, '8.1', '10.1'], dtype='object')
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Use `header=None` na chamada de `pd.read_excel`, dessa forma: `data = pd.read_excel('numero_automoveis_vendidos.xlsx', header=None)`

Comment: Você pode adicionar na pergunta um exemplo de como os dados estão salvos no arquivo .xlsx? e como deve ser a saida esperada?

Comment: Executei com header = None e deu muito certo, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Importa a Biblioteca Pandas
import pandas as pd

print('=== original ===')
df = pd.read_excel('ABC.xlsx');
print(df)
print()

print('=== Modo 1 ===')
#Seta None no index e header(ou numero de inicio de leitura da linha)
df = pd.read_excel('ABC.xlsx', index_col=None, header=None);
print(df)
print()

print('=== Modo 2 ===')
#Seta None header(ou numero de inicio de leitura da linha)
df = pd.read_excel('ABC.xlsx', header=None, names=['Produto','Valor','Unidade']);
print(df)
print()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]